# Hiding the turtle in python turtle drawing

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to make it so that the turtle is hidden from the beginning of the program but even after putting `t.hideturtle()` right below where I declare the turtle as variable t the turtle still seems to show up in the middle of the drawing.

```
import turtle
from random import randint

s = turtle.getscreen()
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.hideturtle()
rx = randint(50,100)
ry = randint(50,100)
width, height = 32,32
s.screensize(width, height)
s.bgcolor("black")

t.goto(0,0)
t.speed(15)

num=10
while num<=1000:
    r = randint(1,5)
    if r == 1:
        t.pencolor("white")
    elif r == 2:
        t.pencolor("#00FFFF")
    elif r == 3:
        t.pencolor("#89CFF0")
    elif r == 4:
        t.pencolor("#0000FF")
    elif r == 5:
        t.pencolor("#00FFFF")
    t.right(25)
    t.circle(num)
    num=num+10
    count=num//10
print("ran",count,"times")
```

Comment: Please narrow down the problem by making a [mre]. To start, try removing the different colors; I don't think they're relevant to the problem. Also, `rx` and `ry` are unused.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue in [11 lines](https://gist.github.com/wjandrea/f479df155a846f904c3f88d9115260dc) (plus 4 blank lines just to match your layout). You can copy it if you want.

Comment: @wjandrea thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a tricky one.

The key problem here is that your first statement creates one turtle and returns you its screen.  That turtle remains visible.  Your second statement creates a new turtle, which you hide.  Change the order to:

```py
t = turtle.Turtle()
s = t.getscreen()
```

and it all works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

@TimRoberts writes:

> The key problem here is that your first statement creates one turtle
> and returns you its screen. That turtle remains visible. Your second
> statement creates a new turtle, which you hide.

This is the problem with mixing turtle's *object-oriented* API and it's *functional* API.  If we change the `import` to force *just* the object-oriented API, and block the functional one, we can do:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
```

or instead do:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()

screen = Screen()
```

And it makes no difference.  By mixing the functional API and the object-oriented API, you can easily unintentionally create the *default* turtle which isn't called for in this code.

Answer (score -1):

I tried this line of code and it worked for me:

```py
import turtle

turtle.hideturtle()
```